# Validar solo letras

Tags: c#

```
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba la primera palabra: ");
            string palabra1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (palabra1.Length < 4 || palabra1.Length > 10)
            {
                Console.Beep();
                Console.WriteLine("Solo palabras de 4 a 10 caracteres");
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Escriba la segunda palabra: ");
            string palabra2 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (palabra2.Length < 4 || palabra2.Length > 10)
            {
                Console.Beep();
                Console.WriteLine("Solo palabras de 4 a 10 caracteres");
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Escriba la tercer palabra: ");
            string palabra3 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (palabra3.Length < 4 || palabra3.Length > 10)
            {
                Console.Beep();
                Console.WriteLine("Solo palabras de 4 a 10 caracteres");
                break;
            }
```

De que manera puedo validar que solo se ingresen letras en palabra1, palabra2 y palabra3? Y si por ejemplo, no se cumple la condicion, que vuelva a empezar el ciclo pidiendo de nuevo la primera palabra, esto esta dentro de un while.

Comment: has oído hablar de regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comprobar si todos los caracteres de un texto cumplen una condición con LinQ:

```
String palabra1 = String.Empty;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escriba la primera palabra: ");
    palabra1 = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
while (!palabra1.All(c => Char.IsLetter(c)));

Console.WriteLine($"Aceptado el texto {palabra1}");
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZCxasMwEIZn6ymupoM1VOAkU00KIWQouFCaQofS4SwfjkC23JPaNAQ/u6u4GAIdJNDxf9/9SPs77ZjG8cubroH9yQdqC3H9UqXpPgshtEXv4Zldw9iKs0h8wGA0fDtTwxOaLvOBI/b@AciNlyKJmWQ/zaBHixVjDmv4m6hd24dT1CZJ7eJ1ySZb13lnSb2xCRTXUpbuvGZTIViEnk1LjLPrHlJZXKgr9yx4IawnXqpXV7ojcTZlh3iOB2MJspsZUxtrMw3rB9gekNWjLymECGgp5dTvf6vbdKOpD1g7IAuBfoKD8@wbplqDGMYxXyxXAvNqoZf1SvQYPwzFLw)</kbd>.